# Retrieve primary ip address with WMI

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

I have developed a program in C# using WMI management classes to dynamically add and remove IP-Addresses to specific network adapter. Everything is working fine so far, but I am unable to differ between the 'primary' and 'secondary' IP-Addresses. I need to know this primary address to prevent removing it from the adapter.

With 'primary' I mean the specific IP-Address witch is shown on the first page of the network adapter properties.

Using netsh, the order of the result is corresponding to this specific order with the primary address first and then the secondary. With WMI and powershell the address are sorted from (numeric) greatest to smallest value.

Can I influence this behavior, or do you have an idea how to determine the first/primary address of the network adapter?  I need the same order as returned by netsh or as shown in the Windows GUI.

*This is how i set the static IP-Addresses, ConfigurationManagmentObject is a Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WMI object:*

```
//Bulding the network address list to set
var addressList = new List<NetworkAddress>();
addressList.Add(this.PrimaryIpAddress);
addressList.AddRange(SecondaryIpAddresses);

// Set IPAddress and Subnet Mask
var enableStaticParameters = this.ConfigurationManagmentObject.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");
var addresses = new List<string>(finalList.Select(o => o.IpAddress));
enableStaticParameters["IPAddress"] = addresses.ToArray();
var subnets = new List<string>(finalList.Select(o => o.Subnet));
enableStaticParameters["SubnetMask"] = subnets.ToArray();
var result = this.ConfigurationManagmentObject.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", enableStaticParameters, null);
```

*And this is how I retrieve the set addresses:*

```
var ipAddresses = (string[])this.ConfigurationManagmentObject.Properties.Cast<PropertyData>().Where(p => p.Name == "IPAddress").Select(p => p.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

The order of the list I set is not reflected by the list I get from the second code. However, it IS reflected by netsh and the windows GUI

Comment: did you get any solution ? do you use *Win32_NetworkAdapter* ?